# hibernate sybase db power function

Tags: hibernate, sybase

We are trying to use sybase function "power" to do mathematical calculation for one of the DB columns.

The hibernate is generating power function as

> pow(?, xyzo0_.AmtScale)

whereas sybase supports power function as Syntax

> POWER( numeric-expression-1, numeric-expression-2 )

We have tried modifying the hibernate.dialect. Have tried

> org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseASE15Dialect
>   org.hibernate.dialect.Sybase11Dialect
>   org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseAnywhereDialect

but all dialects generate the power function as

> pow(?, xyzo0_.AmtScale).

Is this hibernate issue or are we missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this. We added custom implementation by extending the Sybase Dialect class.

In this class constructor, we have called the registerFunction to specify alternative to power function.

> public class XyzDialect extends Sybase11Dialect {
>
> ```
> //constructor   
> XyzDialect() {
>
>   registerFunction("pow", 
>     new StandardSQLFunction("power",  FloatType.INSTANCE));
> }
> ```
>
> }